# Loading menu from a partial view in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to seperate the menu from _Layout.cshtml but I am having difficulties.

My files are located like below.

```
Views/Home/Index
Views/Shared/_Layout
Views/Shared/_Menu
```

In _Layout.cshtml file, I have the code below...

```
@Html.Partial("_Menu")
```

Menu action is located in HomeController, and it looks like below

```
public ActionResult Menu()
{
    MenuModel menu = new MenuModel();
    return PartialView("_Menu", menu);
}
```

_Menu has the code below as first line

```
@model DomainModel.MenuModel
```

When I run the project on VS, everything looks perfect but I doesnt call Menu() action in HomeController. It somehow finds _Menu and displays it perfectly. But I dont understand why it doesnt call Menu() action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Html.Partial("_Menu")`  will just render HTML view, nothing to do with controller. If you want to call a controller use `@{ Html.RenderAction("Menu", "Home"); }`

Comment: Hi, It gives an error "Cannot implicitly convert type void to object".

Comment: @ayilmaz just format use this @{ Html.RenderAction("Menu", "Home"); }

Comment: well, it gives this error "A public action method '_Menu' was not found on controller 'HomeController'"

Comment: @ayilmaz @{ Html.RenderAction("Menu", "Home"); }

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot. so @{ Html.RenderAction("Menu", "Home"); } calls the action. And action return _Menu, I guess

Comment: @ayilmaz yes, But this used to render action with logic, so i supposed MenuModel menu = new MenuModel(); is just for demo.

Answer (score 0):

Actions are cally by request. Therefore you have to send a request e.g. via Ajax to `YourController/YourAction` or type the url in the browser.

`@Html.Partial()` simply renders the view with the given data.

To render a view by calling a action please refer to Ahmends answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/40589584/3936440.